# Change the line height of the post title in HUGO-Xmin theme

Tags: css, r, hugo, blogdown

With R blogdown package, it is easy to build a personal website. I like the style of the [yihui/hugo-xmin](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin) theme for its simplicity. I built a site with the R blogdown package in my folder 'c:/test' on the Windows OS:

```
install.packages('blogdown')
setwd('c:/test')
blogdown::new_site(theme='yihui/hugo-xmin')
```

and I wrote the following text into a .md file in `c:/test/content/post/` folder:

```
---
title: "Summer Holiday in Southern France (VIII): Return to Nice (Videos) 带着俩娃游南法 (第十天): 重返尼斯 (视频)"
author: dapeng
date: "2017-08-17 15:22:06"
slug: summer-holiday-in-southern-france-viii-return-to-nice-videos
categories: [cn]
tags: 
  - cn
---

my text.
```

Then I previewed the site:

```
blogdown::serve_site()
```

However, the post title looks like this:

[image]

I was wondering how to change the line height in the title, which  is too small by default. I added a `line-height`command in `/themes/hugo-xmin/static/css/style.css` like this:

```
.menu, .article-meta, footer { text-align: center; }
.title { font-size: 1.1em; }
footer a { text-decoration: none; }
hr {
  border-style: dashed;
  line-height: 5em;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

But it did not work.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Where is the code? And this is two questions. You should have two different questions, one for each problem

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added a link to the demo codes, and rephrase the question as ONE question with two sub issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not how it works here man. I doubt anyone will clone your git. It's risky. And no one will take the time to sift through all your code to find a problem. You need to post here the markup and CSS that refer to ONLY your problem. It must replicate the error too and it needs to be debuggable (run, even with errors). Using the code snippet here is good, or use JFiddle or Codepen to construct your sample

Comment: If your system is built in some specific framework, find the online editor that supports that framework for online debugging without us downloading anything. Like for React you can use WebPackBin, and for Angular Material you can use Codepen. etc.

Comment: Thanks Luis. I have revised my question with reproducible codes. It is nice to know the tools you mentioned.

Comment: They are still two completely orthogonal questions. You cannot just pretend this is a single question. I only answered the first one. I can answer the second one if it is asked in a separate post.

Comment: OK, Yihui. I am separating them soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title is not in the `<hr>` tag but `<h1>`. Add something like this to your CSS should increase the line-height:

```
h1 { line-height: 1.2em; }
```

I recommend you to learn to [use the Developer Tools of your web browser](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/website-basics.html).

Comment: Oh, it is embarrassing. Sounds like a stupid question.  Thanks!

Comment: No need to be embarrassed :) Don't forget to accept the answer if it works.